# I work remote but CEO is not happy no one is using the shiny new office space, new mandate that everyone has to work 3 days in the office (UK)

Tags: management, united-kingdom, work-life-balance

Background: I am employed as a remote Senior/Mid C# developer at a local-ish company. I have worked remotely for over 10 years at various companies with the usual caveat that comes with all remote positions that yes occasionally I might have to go to the office (company meetings etc once in a while). I am a very productive worker and this has been acknowledge by my boss. I have rescued them from a number of dire situations since I started (~1 year ago). I have excellent communication skills within my team and across departments again highlighted and re-iterated by my boss on several occasions.

Fast forward to now, the company was in the process of finding a new space to consolidate their storage/factory and the office space (as originally they had multiple buildings). All through this process we where assured that other than occasional team meetings or the usual there would be no need for us to work from the office unless we wanted to and for those that wanted to there would be hotdesk/space for them to work from.

A number of days ago one the company CEO's visited the now finished office space and basically saw that there was no one working in it or very few people working from the office and immediately handed down a mandate that from Sept the 5th fully remote working was now being replaced with Hybrid and all expected to be in the office for 3 days a week (this would need putting on a rota as there simply aren't enough desk's). Now none of the impacted department heads/managers were pre-warned to this change.

My boss went to his manager (a director) who confirmed he was also caught off guard and after a discussion between them the outcome is that the director agrees with my boss in that he doesn't see why we (the developers) need to be in. We have proved time and time again the remote "Team" works. The result being that the director said he isn't going to be checking if we are going in (all sounds fine and dandy).

However, I am furious at the situation (it might seem petty to some but remote working is important to me hence why I have been doing to for 10+ years). One of my main issues is yes for now a blind eye might be given to us not working from the office, but there is nothing concrete - it's nothing more than a verbal "*ok I won't say anything"* and if/when there is another random visit by the CEO there's nothing to stop the mandate being enforced.

I have no particular loyalty to the company. I enjoy the work, I like the people and I work hard, but this has thrown me off balance, and I'm stuck between thinking I should stick it out and see what happens and hoping that essentially we never get caught, or starting to look for a new position now (while continuing where I am) and see what comes along.

I know no one can answer this situation for me, but I would be interested in views/opinions any one has to offer.

About me:
I thrive working remotely - an office space simply is not constructive to my working. I tried it once and never did it again. I am more productive when I am not office based, and since there is obviously no commute I tend to work more hours as I get in to the *zone* and I'm happy. I'm not interested in chasing up the promotion ladder as I enjoy being a developer. I'm not pursuing a bigger salary and I'm not looking to move to management although I've been offered it before and it doesn't interest me.

Comment: "I know no one can answer this situation for me, i would be interested in views/opinions any one has to offer." That makes this question off-topic for this site, though.

Comment: My gut feel is that a worker who doesn't come in won't be the one punished, their manager will be. Why not just keep doing what you're doing

Comment: * gifting the OP a couple of commas and full stops.. * ;)

Comment: What does the written work contract say? Does it promise 100 % remote?

Comment: Relevant anecdote: one of my previous employers set a new dress code for an engineering building that no one wanted to follow. So everybody just ignored it and showed up as usual. The employer had the choice between large scale disciplinary action or walking away. After two weeks the rescinded the dress code.

Comment: What the OP is likely worried about is the CEO coming in, seeing nobody, and deciding that  some firings are needed.

Answer (score 5):

A UK answer for a UK question: I would certainly check your employment contract - if you have one.

It should state your "usual place of work"; if the location is your CEO's "shiny new office space", then you're probably out of luck on this one.

If this is the case, I would however just get looking for another job; without prying, I would guess you're probably behind market rate after having stayed put in one place so long, and in the UK (indeed, worldwide), *skilled Software Developers are the rarity* - not jobs.

You should be able to find a different company to work for where remote working is explicitly declared - upfront - in your employment contract. The forward-thinking/smart companies that desperately need talent are using home working as a benefit to lure people in. This really is the best arrangement for both parties, as everyone knows where they stand. If your contract states an address, it's up to the whim of the employer to impose full time office working.

Now, if you **don't** have an employment contract, you're covered under a standard employment contract by law. As for your "usual place of work" - this would probably be your home, as it hasn't been explicitly stated. An employment tribunal would use existing working patterns as a guide here. If your boss wants to issue an employment contract *after the fact*, you can certainly contest this and refuse to sign. If he decided to fire you for this refusal, you would probably have an unfair dismissal case to bring.

Of course, ultimately, the TL;DR version of this is if your CEO wants to cut his own nose off to spite his face, and insist all remote workers come into his office, at the cost of losing his best and long-serving/loyal staff, he'll probably get his way and probably won't see reason, no matter what you do. There's sometimes just no helping people.

And in that situation, I say; get a pay bump and work somewhere different. They need you, not the other way around!

Comment: Clarification: They said they've worked remotely for 10 years and at their current job for one year, not that they've worked remotely for the current job for 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as though your Director has your back - which is **great**, and while they're ultimately going to be limited in what they can do if the CEO decides to play hardball on this you'd be surprised how effective it can be when a Director makes an argument about losing/alienating a star performer so it might be worth sticking it out for now and see what the reality is on the 5th.

I used to work at a place where the MD/owner did very similar - although this was over headphones. He objected to people wearing them in the office - and while he was right that *some* of the staff shouldn't have been in their roles he went overboard and issued a blanket ban. Headphones to me are like Remote working is to you - my productivity takes a serious nosedive if I can't zone out the office with them, like your situation my director understood and made it clear that this wasn't something she was going to enforce on me and would back me if  the MD complained. So I carried on using them, the MD made numerous whirlwind visits to our office in subsequent months and I had headphones on every time. Not a word was said.

So it *might* be similar in your situation - the CEO has made a knee-jerk reaction to something in the moment and will move on from it.

I can totally understand your position re: Remote vs In-person for what it's worth - and given it's importance to you I can appreciate you might want something more concrete so it might be worth digging out your contract and seeing what it says about your "Primary place of work" - because if it *doesn't* say the office is it but says remote or even if it says the "old" office they *can't* unilaterally change that on you without your agreement unless there's a suitable mobility clause, and even then the change can't be "unreasonable" and it can be deemed so for various reasons - financial burden on the employee, severe disruption to family life etc. Obviously getting into a legal wrangling over it is a nuclear option, but knowing that you've got that backstop might make you feel more secure.

Comment: Agreed to it being a knee-jerk reaction. In fact, it seems to me that what the CEO really wants isn't that OP is in the office 3 days/week — it's simply that the new office must look busy and full and well-used. And that will happen even if OP is never there. — However, it _won't_ happen if lots of OP's colleagues take the same decision; and it could cause bad feeling if OP is seen as receiving a special privilege, so it's not as clear-cut as that.

Comment: @gidds Perhaps they should hire some guys.  Rent it out for temporary co-working spaces.  See if the CEO notices :)

Answer (score 2):

> I thrive working remotely - an office space simply is not constructive
> to my working. I tried it once and never did it again.

Since this is clearly very important to you, it's time to start looking for a new job that promises to be fully remote.

Even if you "get away with it" for a while, CEO's tend to get their way eventually.

Perhaps while you are searching, you'll find out that it's a non-issue and you can call off the job search. But I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do three things:

1. Talk to the manager that supports you.
2. Calculate the cost of this change to you (transport, food, and I’d
   count the time of commuting at about half my normal rate), and based
   on that suggest a raise that would be needed to put you in the same
   financial position as before.
3. Look for a new job.

My own calculation was £6,000 savings per year working from home, £10,000 more salary needed based on 40% tax, and £11,500 more cost to the company due to employer NI. The number might surprise your CEO, and definitely show him that he will have a fight on his hands.

PS. Blatantly copying from Rotisev: If you manage to get a pay rise, even if it is less than you wanted, that will help you when you find your next job.

PS. Your employment contract is only relevant if you refuse to come in, the CEO fires you, and you want money for unfair dismissal; in the long term it’s not relevant, because the reality of your job changes. You were happy to do the job for £X a month, you are not happy to do the job under changed conditions for the same money.